# How to "Run As Web Application" an App Engine Backend in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio to create a GCM Android application and generate an App Engine Backend. At the moment the Android part works fine, but I can't understand how to launch the Backend part. [This](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae) document describes a Run As -> Web Application possibility in Eclipse with the Google plugin installed, but how can I achieve the same effect while using Android Studio? Since the generated application is a Maven app, I tried to build it using Maven and then deploy the .war file on a local Glassfish server - the application runs fine, but it is unable to fetch the registered devices list and the Send message option seems to do nothing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with App Engine projects working on a GlassFish Server.  There is a maven goal appengine:devappserver which is the testing server that is designed to run App Engine projects.  Perhaps you can try with that?

Answer (score 0):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html

> 1. Deploy the sample backend server When you're ready to deploy an update to your ( the sample ) production backend in the cloud, you can
>      do that easily from the IDE. Click on the “Maven Projects” button on
>      the right edge of the IDE, under Plugins > App Engine, right-click and
>      run the appengine:update goal.
>
> As soon as the update is deployed, you can also access your endpoints
>   through the APIs Explorer at
>   http://.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer.
>
> For testing and debugging, you can also run your backend server
>   locally without having to deploy your changes to the production
>   backend. To run the backend locally, just set the value of
>   LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to true in CloudEndpointUtils.java in the App Engine
>   module.

Comment: In the current Android Studio version (0.5.3), this no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following (it worked for me):

1. Open your project in android studio Open CloudEndpointUtils.java from your projectname-endpoints project
2. Update the LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN. It should say:
   protected static final boolean LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = true;
3. Click on the View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects
4. In the Maven Projects window, 
   Expand projecname-AppEngine -> Plugins -> appengine
5. Right mouse click on 'appengine:devserver'
6. Click on Run 'projectname-AppEngine [...'
7. Browse to yourlocalhostip:8080 to see the backend